# std::lower_bound slower for std::vector than std::map::find

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, vector, dictionary

I wrote a class to act as a wrapper around a sequential container (`std::vector`/`std::queue`/`std::list`) to have the interface of a `std::map`, for performance when using small numbers of small objects.  The coding was all remarkably simple given the algorithms that already existed.  This code is obviously *highly* trimmed from my full code, but shows the problem.

```
template <class key_, 
          class mapped_, 
          class traits_ = std::less<key_>,
          class undertype_ = std::vector<std::pair<key_,mapped_> >
         >
class associative
{
public:
    typedef traits_ key_compare;
    typedef key_ key_type;
    typedef mapped_ mapped_type;
    typedef std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type> value_type;
    typedef typename undertype_::allocator_type allocator_type;
    typedef typename allocator_type::template rebind<value_type>::other value_allocator_type;
    typedef typename undertype_::const_iterator const_iterator;

    class value_compare {
        key_compare pred_;
    public:
        inline value_compare(key_compare pred=key_compare()) : pred_(pred) {}
        inline bool operator()(const value_type& left, const value_type& right) const {return pred_(left.first,right.first);}
        inline bool operator()(const value_type& left, const key_type& right) const {return pred_(left.first,right);}
        inline bool operator()(const key_type& left, const value_type& right) const {return pred_(left,right.first);}
        inline bool operator()(const key_type& left, const key_type& right) const {return pred_(left,right);}
        inline key_compare key_comp( ) const {return pred_;}
    };
    class iterator  {
    public:       
        typedef typename value_allocator_type::difference_type difference_type;
        typedef typename value_allocator_type::value_type value_type;
        typedef typename value_allocator_type::reference reference;
        typedef typename value_allocator_type::pointer pointer;
        typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        inline iterator(const typename undertype_::iterator& rhs) : data(rhs) {}
    inline reference operator*() const { return reinterpret_cast<reference>(*data);}
        inline pointer operator->() const {return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(structure_dereference_operator(data));}
        operator const_iterator&() const {return data;}
    protected:
        typename undertype_::iterator data;
    };

    template<class input_iterator>
    inline associative(input_iterator first, input_iterator last) : internal_(first, last), comp_() 
    {if (std::is_sorted(internal_.begin(), internal_.end())==false) std::sort(internal_.begin(), internal_.end(), comp_);}

inline iterator find(const key_type& key) {
    iterator i = std::lower_bound(internal_.begin(), internal_.end(), key, comp_);
    return (comp_(key,*i) ? internal_.end() : i);
}

protected:
    undertype_ internal_;
    value_compare comp_;
};
```

SSCCE at http://ideone.com/Ufn7r, full code at http://ideone.com/MQr0Z (note: resulting times as IdeOne are highly erratic, probably due to server load, and do not clearly show the results in question)

I tested with `std::string`, and PODs from 4 to 128 bytes, ranging from 8 to 2000 elements with MSVC10.

I expected higher performance for (1) creating from a range for small objects, (2) random insertion/erasure for small numbers of small objects, and (3) lookup for all objects.  Surprisingly, the vector was *significantly* faster for creating from a range for all tests, and faster for random erasure  depending on size up to about 2048 bytes (512 4-byte objects, or 128 16-byte objects, etc).  However, most shocking of all, was that the `std::vector` using `std::lower_bound` was slower than the `std::map::find` for all PODs.  The difference was miniscule for 4 and 8-byte PODs, and but for 128-byte PODs, `std::vector` was up to 36% slower!  However, for `std::string`, the `std::vector` was 6% faster on average.

I feel like `std::lower_bound` on a sorted `std::vector` should have outperformed `std::map` due to better cache locality/smaller memory size, and since the `map` can be imperfectly balanced, or in the *worst case* it should *match* `std::map`, but can't for the life of me think of any reason that `std::map` should be faster.  My only thought is the predicate is somehow slowing it down, but I can't figure out how.  So the question is: **How could it be that `std::lower_bound` on a sorted `std::vector` be outperformed by a `std::map` (in MSVC10)?**

[EDIT] I've confirmed that `std::lower_bound` on `std::vector<std::pair<4BYTEPOD,4BYTEPOD>>` uses fewer *comparisons* on average than `std::map<4BYTEPOD,4BYTEPOD>::find` (by 0-0.25), but my implementation is still up to 26% slower.

[POST-ANSWER-EDIT] I made a SSCCE at http://ideone.com/41iKt that removes all unneeded fluff, and clearly shows that `find` on the sorted `vector` is slower than that of the `map`, by ~15%.

Comment: I noticed that it was returning the wrong value for key not found after I posted the question, but that doesn't relate to the issue.

Comment: Note that you're reinventing the wheel here -- Boost contains this exact functionality in [Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/libs/container/), namely `boost::container::flat_map<>`. At the least, you may want to compare your implementation to that one to check for any notable differences.

Comment: @ildjarn: someday I'll learn to boost.  I'll compare, though I'm pretty sure at this point it's the predicate.

Comment: “Both std::lower_bound and set::find take time proportional to log N, but the constants of proportionality are very different. Using g++ (...) it takes X seconds to perform a million lookups in a sorted vector<double> of a million elements, and almost twice as long (...) using a set. Moreover, the set uses almost three times as much memory (48 million bytes) as the vector (16.8 million).” [Matt Austern: Why You Shouldn't Use `set`, and What You Should Use Instead](http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf)

Comment: @sehe: Exactly.  So why is the `vector` in this code 3 times slower than `map`?

Comment: I've been looking at the assembly output on g++ on my Linux box, and there is no indication of copying in the predicate or anything like that. And the results for a size of 128 are really different from the results for a size of 127. It is very odd.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Since 127 is one from a power of two, a binary search will take one additional check 50% of the time.  That's a change from 8->9 predicate checks, should be ~13% slower.

Comment: With 16 8-byte elements, this SSCCEE does 18733834 lookups with map, and 50356323 lookups with vector.  My full code tests other things as well, gets timings of 18663465 lookups with map and 14495229 with vector.

Comment: @MooingDuck - I'm talking about the size of `payload`, not the size of the vector.

Comment: @Omnifarious: In that case it might have switched from shifting to multiplication, which implies that the pointer arithmetic might be related.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a sorted vector faster at lookup than a map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336239/is-a-sorted-vector-faster-at-lookup-than-a-map)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a somewhat more interesting nut to crack! Before discussing my findings so far, let me point out that the `associative::find()` function behaves differently to `std::map::find()`: if the key isn't found the former returns the lower bound while the latter returns `end()`. To fix this, `associative::find()` needs to be changed to become something like this:

```
auto rc = std::lower_bound(this->internal_.begin(), this->internal_.end(), key, this->comp_);
return rc != this->internal_.end() && !this->comp_(key, rc->first)? rc: this->internal_.end();
```

Now that we are more likely to compare apples to apples (I haven't verified if the logic is really correct now), let's go on to investigate the performance. I'm not quite convinced that the approach used to test performance really hold water but I'm sticking with it for now and I could definitely improve the performance of the `associative` container. I don't think I have quite found all performance issues in the code but, at least, made some progress. The biggest is to noticed that the comparison function used in the `associative` is pretty bad because it keeps making copies. This is putting this container somewhat at a disadvantage. If you are checking the comparator now you probably don't see it because it looks as if this comparator **is** passing by reference! The issue is actually rather subtle: the underlying container has a `value_type` of `std::pair<key_type, mapped_type>` but the comparator is taking `std::pair<key_type const, mapped_type>` as argument! Fixing this seems to give the associative container quite a bit of a performance boost.

To implement a comparator class which has not opportunity to fail matching the arguments exactly I'm using a simple helper to detect if a type is a `std::pair<L, R>`:

```
template <typename>               struct is_pair                  { enum { value = false }; };
template <typename F, typename S> struct is_pair<std::pair<F, S>> { enum { value = true }; };
```

... and then I replaced the comparator with this, slightly more complicated, one:

```
class value_compare {
    key_compare pred_;
public:
    inline value_compare(key_compare pred=key_compare()) : pred_(pred) {}
    template <typename L, typename R>
    inline typename std::enable_if<is_pair<L>::value && is_pair<R>::value, bool>::type
    operator()(L const& left, R const& right) const {
        return pred_(left.first,right.first);
    }
    template <typename L, typename R>
    inline typename std::enable_if<is_pair<L>::value && !is_pair<R>::value, bool>::type
    operator()(L const& left, R const& right) const {
        return pred_(left.first,right);
    }
    template <typename L, typename R>
    inline typename std::enable_if<!is_pair<L>::value && is_pair<R>::value, bool>::type
    operator()(L const& left, R const& right) const {
        return pred_(left,right.first);
    }
    template <typename L, typename R>
    inline typename std::enable_if<!is_pair<L>::value && !is_pair<R>::value, bool>::type
    operator()(L const& left, R const& right) const {
        return pred_(left,right);
    }
    inline key_compare key_comp( ) const {return pred_;}
};
```

This generally gets the two approaches quite a bit closer together. Given that I would expect that the `std::vector<T>` with `lower_bound()` approach should be a lot better than using `std::map<K, T>` I feel the investigation isn't over, yet.

**Addendum**:

Rethinking the exercise a bit more I spotted why I felt uncomfortable with the implementation of the predicate class: it is **way** to complex! This can be done a lot simpler by **not** using `std::enable_if` for a change: this nicely reduces the code to something which is much easier to read. The key is to get the key:

```
template <typename Key>
Key const& get_key(Key const& value)                  { return value; }
template <typename Key,  typename Value>
Key const& get_key(std::pair<Key, Value> const& pair) { return pair.first; }
```

With this implementation to get hold of a "key" from either a value or a pair of values, the predicate object can just define one very simple function call operator:

```
template <typename L, typename R>
bool operator()(L const& l, R const& r)
{
    return this->pred_(get_key<key_type>(l), get_key<key_type>(r));
}
```

There is a slight trick in this as well, though: the expected `key_type` needs to be passed to the `get_key()` function. Without this the predicate wouldn't work in cases where the `key_type` is itself a `std::pair<F, S>` of objects.

Comment: Well, the compiler needs to come up with a `std::pair<K const, V>` and it has a `std::pair<K, V>`. Just chopping in a `const` won't work - the `const` version can be specialized or something.

Comment: Yes. This is why I think there is more but I haven't tracked other problems down, yet. Running the code through some sort of profiler to see where the time is spent seems like the next stop.

Comment: This might indicate that the search indeed wants to be stopped early: since we know that there are no duplicate values in the range (if we correctly implemented the logic for an associative container), we might want to make sure we haven't found the correct value before continuing to search, at least when we need to search down the right branch of the tree.

Comment: Dietmar Kühl: ran the code through a profiler, results in the question.  Nothing unusual to my eyes (once I fixed the predicate) to what you suggested.  I also confirmed that the implimentation of map being used does _not_ quit early when it reaches an exact match.

Comment: @Mooing : Can you give us a TL;DR on what the problem was? Or was the comparator the entirety of the problem after all?

Comment: @ildjarn: With my mini-test suite, the comparator was the entirety of the problem after all.  With my full application it's still slower, but that is _technically_ outside the scope of this SO question/SSCCE, and I can think of no more information to provide.

Comment: @ildjarn: Next question is why is vector slower than map in my fuller code, and faster in my SSCCE?

Comment: @ildjarn: http://ideone.com/MQr0Z (Though IDEOne's timings are unusable for comparison)

Comment: While that last edit is much cleaner, my code doesn't force the predicate parameters to be keys, allowing more flexible comparitors.

Answer (score 1):

I have a guess. First, `lower_bound` **must** do *log2(n)* comparisons, regardless. This means that there is never a time (like there would be for `find`) when it can stop early. Secondly, for data types that are larger than a certain size, there must be a multiply operation involved in any pointer arithmetic for the vector. Whereas for the map, it's simply a pointer load of a 4 (or 8 on 64-bit) byte value from memory.

The x86 has some nice instructions for doing very fast multiplies by powers of two during indexing calculations. But they only work for small powers of two as they are designed for indexing arrays of integer-like entities. For larger numbers it has to actually use an integer multiply instruction that's significantly slower.

When you do `lower_bound` you have to do exactly *log2(n)* of these multiplies. But for `find` it can be cut off at a smaller number for half the values. This means that their effect is going to be much larger for `lower_bound` than any other method.

As an aside... in my opinion, `::std::map` should be implemented as a B-tree where each node is a page in size. Virtual memory sets it up so that basically every program that has a significantly large data structure will end up having parts of that structure paged out under memory pressure. Having each node only store one value risks creating a nearly worst case in which you have to page in a whole page for every comparison for a *log2(n)* depth, where if you used a b-tree, your worst paging case would be *logx(n)* pages where *x* is the number of values per node.

This also has the nice side-effect of lessening the bad effects of cache-line boundaries. There will be a LCM of the (key, value) tuple size and the cache-line size. Having multiple (key, value) pairs in a node sets it up so this LCM is much more likely to happen and X pairs will take exactly Y cache lines. But if each node contains only one pair, this will basically never happen unless the node size is an exact multiple of the cache-line size.

Comment: I think the multiplication can safely be disregarded for the performance calculation.

Comment: @SimonRichter - Maybe you're right. But it does neatly explain the observed behavior.

Comment: Are there any examples of a std::map being implemented as a B-tree? To fully comply with the standard there are a lot of performance and consistency guarantees that you need to get just right, and (not coincidentally) with red-black trees everything just falls into place without much effort. I've seen an attempt to implement map with other sorts of trees and it's harder than it looks; multimap in particular posed some challenges.

Comment: @StilesCrisis - multimap would be really tricky to implement with a B-tree. I would have to examine the spec carefully to figure out if it could be met with a B-tree for a standard map.

Comment: @Omnifarious I don't know if a B-tree would work for `std::map`'s requirements, but there shouldn't be any problems allowing for duplicate keys.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Well, ideally duplicate keys result in only one key being stored with multiple associated values.

Comment: A btree doesnt sound relevant, as it still must find the correct value in each node, so with large numbers of elemts per node, that reduces to... std::lower_bound.  Thats reason to match, not beat.  Second, I dont thin std::lower_bound does exactly logN comparisons, and can quit early just like std::find, _except_ that find knows each key is unique.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The reason B-tree's are better has nothing to do with the OPs original question exactly, except that it (like the OPs code) is an alternate data structure for implementing map-like functionality. So the fact that `::std::lower_bound` has to be used isn't relevant. B-trees are better because of their virtual memory paging characteristics as compared to one-value per node solutions like red-black trees.

Comment: @MooingDuck: And you're wrong about `::std::lower_bound` being able to end early. In order to be sure that it really has found the lower_bound it can't stop when it merely finds a node that's neither less or greater. It has to find the last value that's less, and the first value that's greater or equal. This means it has to narrow the top and bottom bound until it shrinks to one value. That will always require _log2(n)_ successive halvings.

Comment: @Omnifarious: You're right.  I think that is probably the issue then.  I'll have to impliment my own find function that knows theres no duplicates.  That seems especially likely since increased numbers of elements show decreased performance.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I checked, MSVC10's `std::_Tree` checks O(log(n)) and does _not_ bail out early for an exact match, so that doesn't account for the difference.

Comment: @Omnifarious: After much additional testing, I think the pointer arithmetic is to blame for the difference :(

Comment: Mostly.  The bigger prroblem was the comparison object doing copies.  The number of comparisons was equal.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Yeah, both ideas were guesses. I was annoyed that my first idea was poo-pooed though. The second idea was proven wrong when you looked at the code and discovered it didn't short-circuit.

Comment: @Omnifarious: The first idea was poo-poo'd because in my _example_ there was a much bigger problem.  But you were dead on for the underlying problem as asked by the question.  I can't accept both answers :(

Comment: @MooingDuck - Oh, no worries. I'm not hung up about it. But yeah, I should've spotted the copy problem, which was much more serious. I didn't delve into the mechanics of your comparator.

Comment: @MooingDuck: On the early exit from b-search: test carefully: sometimes the extra comparison for the exit condition takes longer than just running the rest of the search.

Comment: @Omnifarious: If you were going to try a B-tree, try page size and also cache-line size. I read an interesting paper where they tried a cache-line sized B-tree and it worked very well. I don't have a reference though.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Oh and also, if you use small enough ranges you might be able to exploit a CPU like Itanium, or x86 instructions from AVX or SSE-4 to do all comparisons in parallel. One instruction to compare. One to branch.

Comment: @ZanLynx: (1) we already checked and established cutting out early was bad. (2) The comparisons are dependent on each other, and are not parallelizable.

Comment: @MooingDuck: In a sorted array, subtract the comparison from all array members. The first positive result is the first item greater than the comparison item. I'll have to check but I think SSe4 or AVX have something for this?

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, but you could store the first 4 bytes of the string as a 32-bit number in the index. Works amazingly well.

Comment: @ZanLynx: This is supposed to be a generalized container, so you'd be imposing that requirement on each and every object that anyone would want to use as a key.  That sounds like a terrible idea.