# Fastest way to speed up map<string,int> .find() in c++ . Where the keys are in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map with about 100,000 pairs . Is there any way that i can speed up searching when using find(), given that the keys are in alphabetical order. Also how should i go about doing it. I know that you can specify a new comparator when you create the map. But will that speed up the find() function at all?

Thanks in advance.

[solved] Thanks a bunch guys i have decided to go with a vector and use lower and upperbound to "snip" some of the searching.

Also i am new here is there any way to mark this question as answered , or pick a best answer?

Comment: If your compiler supports it try `std::unordered_map` instead.

Comment: P.S. having the keys in alphabetical order doesn't matter, `map` will rearrange them to be alphabetical anyway.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Just because I'm disagreeable: it depends on the comparitor :D

Comment: To mark the question as answered, you pick a best answer with the tick on the left-hand side of the answer, underneath the voting buttons.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A different comparator will only speed up find if it manages to do the comparison faster (which, for strings will usually be pretty difficult).

If you're basically inserting all the data in order, then doing the searching, it may be faster to use a `std::vector` with `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`.

If you don't really care about ordering, and just want to find the data as quickly as possible, you might find that `std::unordered_map` works better for you.

Edit: Just for the record: the way you "might find" or "may find" those things is normally by profiling. Depending on the situation, it might be enough faster that it's pretty obvious even in simple testing, so profiling isn't really necessary, but if there's (much) doubt, or you want to quantify the effect, a profiler is probably the right way to do it.

Comment: Regarding the sorted `std::vector<>`, see also [Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/libs/container/)'s [`boost::container::flat_map<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx) for a pre-written, pre-tested implementation.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I removed the downvote.  I do have a tendency to be disagreeable.

Answer (score 4):

`std::map` is already taking advantage of the fact the keys are in alphabetical order - it guarantees that itself. You aren't going to be able to improve it by changing the comparator (one assumes it's already a reasonably efficient string comparison).

Have you considered using `unordered_map` (aka `hash_map` in various implementations pre C++11? It should be able to search in O(1) instead of O(log(n)) for `std::map`.

You could also look into something slightly more exotic, like a trie, but that's not part of the standard library so you'd either have to find one elsewhere or roll your own, so I'd suggest `unordered_map` is a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `std::find` to find elements, you should switch to using `map::find` (you don't really say in your question.) `map::find` uses the fact that the map is ordered to search much faster.

If that's still not good enough, you might look into a hash container such as `unordered_map` rather than `map`.

Comment: That's a good point. The question really doesn't make it clear. Using `std::find` would basically be the worst case for searching, both algorithmically and in terms of memory access pattern.

Comment: Actually, if the comparator you use for `std::find` is the same as the one you're using for the map ordering, couldn't `std::find` be specialized to use member `find`?

Comment: @bames53 No, because `std::find` doesn't get passed or know what the container is. It just does a linear search.

Comment: @bames53: it _could_ be, but it's not required to be, and I've never seen an implementation do it, since it's _far_ harder than it sounds.

Comment: @MarkB That makes sense. Though I think it could be done if the iterators provide access to the containers (like debug iterators have for validity checking). Obviously it would be bad to rely on an implementation doing that and so it wouldn't be worth implementing in the first place, except as a curiousity.

Answer (score 2):

I've put in a vote for `unordered_map` but I wanted to also make another point.

One of the things that can hurt performance on modern machines is poor use of the cache. A map is going to have nodes allocated all over the place and there won't be much locality of reference. Also since it has to store a bunch of pointers between nodes it will use up more memory.

At the recent [*Going Native 2012*](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012) conference Bjarne Stroustroup gave an [interesting talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style) that touched on this topic. He compared `vector` and `list` performance at a task involving a lot of random insertions and deletions, where it might seem `list` ought to have dominated, but because of the memory size and layout issue `vector` was in fact the fastest by far. Take a look at [his slides](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12Cpp11Style.pdf), starting at slide 43.

`unordered_map` gives you direct access to the element and so it probably means even less hopping around in memory than trying to stick your data in a `vector` (and thus better performance than `vector`) so my comment is simply an admonishment to always keep your memory access pattern in mind for performance

Comment: I liked his graph of the comparisons of their speeds during that talk.

Comment: Locality is good, but only for linear stuff.  A binary search on a vector can be _slower_ than a map.

Comment: I wonder if a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays) would be faster than a sorted array?

Comment: @MooingDuck well the slides do have the graph :)

Comment: @MooingDuck Why would a binary search of a `vector` be _slower_ than searching a `map`? In both cases you'll be hopping around in memory, until in the `vector` case the range has been reduced to where it fits in a cache line. Unless all the `map` nodes were allocated together the `map` will never get that benefit, and then you're only likely to benefit if the map is small. And the `vector` elements will be smaller so the range that fits in cache will have more elements than the `map` could fit in.

Comment: @MooingDuck  I think the only way `map` could be faster would be if by chance most of the nodes you traverse happen to be close to each other.

Comment: @MarkRansom `map` generally use trees. They should be faster for insertion and deletion but I don't yet see why they'd be faster for searching.

Comment: @bames53: cache lines are small, in most cases each element is in it's own line, so vector gets no benefit whatsoever except _sometimes_ the last comparison.  Meanwhile, vector needs to do pointer arithmetic that a map does not.  (Assuming no paging happens in both tests)

Comment: @bames53, I was speaking of a specific kind of tree that I don't think is used by `map`. Follow the link.

Comment: @MarkRansom `map`s usually use red-black trees which are balanced while simple binary trees' degenerate to linked lists in the worst case. So I don't think binary trees have any advantage in particular to offer.

Comment: @MooingDuck Well maybe cache lines wasn't what I meant. It just seems to me that with `vector` you'll start getting lots of cache hits once the range is at a certain size, whereas that's unlikely to happen with `map`. I would think that cache hits would by far outweigh pointer arithmetic, but I guess I'll have to look at real data to verify that.

Comment: @bames53: I very much thought so too.  I spend many days testing before I gave up and switched back to `map`.  (vector is faster for creation/insertion/removal though!)

Comment: @bames53 I've never studied an implementation of a red-black tree so I don't know how they're structured, but the wikipedia entry implies that nodes require pointers. The binary array has no pointers, it is tightly packed.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh, I guess your link was pointing to a specific representation of a binary tree, i.e. a heap in an array. That link talks about that representation of binary trees having better locality of reference, but it's comparing to regular binary trees rather than to sorted arrays. A heap, as a partially sorted array, is faster than a fully sorted array for many things.

Comment: @MooingDuck Your claim that `vector` was faster for you at insertion and deletion made me even more skeptical. I went and wrote some quick tests comparing `vector` against `set` (since `set` provides a more comparable interface and should share the performance characteristics of `map`). [Here's my code](http://ideone.com/Vv5Ra). With this code I get the results I expect: `binary_search` of `vector` is faster than member `find` on `set`, and `insert`/`erase` is faster on `set` than `vector` (well `insert` is anyway, I'm cheating a bit to speed up `vector` for you by erasing from the end)

Comment: @bames53: For my tests I forgot to specify that I was only using 8-32 objects, which is why the vector was faster.  For 30+ objects, you're right the map is much faster.  As for lookup, I altered your test to not use chrono, replaced binary_search with lower_bound, and made it so compilers can't cheat (http://ideone.com/0viqj).  The vector appears twice as fast as the map, I'll review my old tests.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah, that clears it up. I ran the tests with 100,000 as a lower bound. I can definitely believe that searching a map and inserting into a vector would be faster for N that small. That should have occurred to me.

Comment: @bames53: when I compared your tests to [my old ones](http://ideone.com/41iKt) I realized your vector lookup "cheats" if the element is not found.  If you make it return `end` if the element is not found like the map does, the vector is slower.  (This is fair, since the map.find has this exact same logic inside: lower_bound followed by end if element not found)  See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784732).

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm not sure that's even necessary. For small N it doesn't seems unreasonable that `map` would win regardless of `vector` cheating that way, though I never tested it. And for larger N, unless I'm screwing something up [here](http://ideone.com/1u4zc) is a modification of your tests that shows `vector` lookup winning.