# How to get a reference of an element in a set in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, set, element

I defined a class `Movie`. And that class has a

```
static set<Movie> movies;
```

I also have a static member function:

```
static Movie& find_by_title(string);
```

I'm returning a reference, because I want to modify the movie once I find it (I want to rate it). So, in the implementation I have

```
Movie& Movie::find_by_title(string title) {
  set<Movie>::iterator it;
  for (it = movies.begin(); it != movies.end(); ++it)
    if (it->title == title) return *it;
}
```

But it returns an error, because `*it` has a type of `const Movie` (and the function returns `Movie&`). But then how to get that element in a way I can change it? A pointer would also be ok, anything that would make it possible to change the element afterwards.

`movies.find(*it)` also returns an iterator to a `const Movie`, so it also doesn't work when I try to return `*(movies.find(*it))`.

Comment: You cannot legally get a non-const reference to an element of a `std::set<>`.

Comment: I hope you don't plan to change this element once it is stored in `std::set`

Comment: Yeah, I planned on changing it. I wanted that set to act like a database (just a temporary one, of course). I tried implementing the "database" with writing and reading from files on disk, but files are too complicated for me in C++, so I chose this approach.

Comment: Refer to [what happens when you modify an element of an std::set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908949/what-happens-when-you-modify-an-element-of-an-stdset).

Comment: That cleared things for me, thanks. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a const reference, and make the methods for setting the rating const, and declare the member variables you have to change to be mutable... but that's probably not a good idea. mutable members are really intended for things that aren't logically part of the classes 'value'.

You're probably best off not using a std::set. Sets are a special purpose container that makes certain guarantees with pretty narrow uses. [Here's](http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf) an article that talks about what std::set is good for, and it outlines four conditions that should hold before you decide to use one:

- The collection can potentially grow so large that the difference between O(N) and O(log N) is important.
- The number of lookups is the same order of magnitude as the number of insertions; there aren't so few insertions that insertion speed is irrelevant.
- Elements are inserted in random order, rather than being inserted in order.
- Insertions and lookups are interleaved; we don't have distinct insertion and lookup phases.

When *all* of those conditions hold then std::set may be a good option. Otherwise, you may well be best off using a vector (probably wrapped in a class that provides a set-like interface).

Comment: I've written a class that wrapped a vector with a map's interface.  Turned out the map was faster.  Given that, I can't imagine _any_ reason one would want a vector wrapped with a set-like interface.  +1 for everything else though.

Comment: @MooingDuck We've discussed the map vs. vector speed thing [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336239/why-is-vector-faster-than-map-in-one-test-but-not-the-other). The speed is quite dependent on several factors. It's not a given that the map is faster. I think it's reasonable to consider std::vector the 'default' container type and only use another container when there's a strong reason, such as the four conditions above holding, or perhaps if a different set of conditions holds: small input size and/or performance irrelevant, vector's interface fits badly but not worth adapting.

Answer (score 3):

The inner workings of `std::set` *require* that the element not be modified once it's inserted into the set. If you tried to modify it the internal structures would be inconsistent and *bad things would happen*.

If your data elements can be split into two parts, one that has a key which does not change and another which you will be changing, use a `std::pair<const key,data>` for the two parts and place them into a `std::map`.