# How do I perform an (almost-)branch-less binary search on arbitrary sorted data?

Tags: c++, binary-search, branch-prediction

How do I perform an (almost-)branch-less binary search on arbitrary sorted arrays in a preferably portable fashion? (e.g. code that helps compilers generate the CMOV instruction would be great for this.)

By "almost" I mean "containing as few branches as possible".

Comment: @PeterWood: What have I tried? lol, the answer I posted below.

Comment: @PeterWood The guy's answering his own question, which is OK. But I believe it's meant to be community wiki.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: no, it's not supposed to be community wiki. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/. Summary: community wiki is for when a collaborative answer is needed. Personally I occasionally use it to prevent myself getting rep for a particular answer, but community wiki is *not* a stick to beat people with when we think they shouldn't get rep for a particular answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a version of `std::lower_bound` which had only 1 branch (namely, the `begin != end` test) when I tested it with Visual C++ 2012 (64-bit):

```
template<class FwdIt, class T, class P>
FwdIt branchless_lower_bound(FwdIt begin, FwdIt end, T const &val, P pred)
{
    while (begin != end)
    {
        FwdIt middle(begin);
        std::advance(middle, std::distance(begin, end) >> 1);
        FwdIt middle_plus_one(middle);
        ++middle_plus_one;
        bool const b = pred(*middle, val);
        begin = b ? middle_plus_one : begin;
        end = b ? end : middle;
    }
    return begin;
}
```

32-bit with SSE2 support would probably be able to use the Conditional-Move instruction as well, to gain similar speed.

Now the speed *should* be competitive with linear search for small arrays... but it might be worth checking.

---

Interestingly, I found that for a `vector<int>` up to size (approximately) 45 on my CPU, a linear search is still faster! Not sure why though, or if my measurement was accurate...

---

Also turns out that this isn't any faster than a branching binary search on my i5 CPU.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: It's an (almost-)branchless `lower_bound` function, hence the name... =P

Comment: With one branch. So perhaps `branchesless_lower_bound` :)

Comment: "but it might be worth checking" with a huge array in modern CPUs

Comment: another interesting "std::lower_bound" post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784732/stdlower-bound-slower-for-stdvector-than-stdmapfind

Comment: how are the conditionals `b? ... : ...;` not two other branches?

Comment: @rhalbersma: compile it and see? Conditional move instructions are one way that compilers can avoid branches for sufficiently simple uses of `?:`. Actually these days avoiding branches it a somewhat naive way to look at it. What you actually want to avoid is wasting the instruction pipeline. Branches are one thing that sometimes do that. Mehrdad is right that performance claims "might" be worth checking before making them ;-)

Comment: @Mehrdad: presumably you could make it actually branchless if you wanted, with some template trickery to unroll the loop based on the size of `iterator_traits<FwdIt>::difference_type`. No doubt that would make it slower for small arrays, though, and arguably it would call `pred` more times than `std::lower_bound` is allowed to, since "the number of bits in the difference type" is a pretty dodgy `O(1)` term.

Comment: @SteveJessop: That's an interesting idea... never thought about using `sizeof(difference_type)` for this. Not sure how to implement it exactly myself but if you have a suggested implementation I'd be interested in seeing it! :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: well, it could be `numeric_limits<T>::digits` rather than `sizeof`. I think the basic trick for loop unrolling is to write a function that does the body once and then calls the n-1 instantiation of itself. n == 0 version does nothing. Then rely on inlining.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yeah that part is straightforward enough, but the part that confuses me is what do I do if `begin` and `end` are the same? Just keep recursing?

Comment: @Mehrdad: yes, if you want to be branchless then you just ensure that cranking the binary search step an extra time won't move `middle` once you've found the right place. Then crank it 64 times and you're sorted. Slowly, but branchlessly :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: loll I'll give it a try if/when I get the chance xD

Comment: Although I suddenly realize that the compiler might object to inlining that much code, it might take a bit of persuasion.

Comment: @SteveJessop: lol yeah. Does an unconditional jump count as a "branch" (in terms of pipeline issues)?

Comment: I dunno, it's your question ;-) Probably not, in the sense that modern processors probably handle an unconditional jump more-or-less as if it wasn't there. In hot code, at least. But one plausible definition of "branchless" would be that after optimization and code generation, the resulting assembly code consists of a single basic block. Then you don't need unconditional jumps, you just need to put everything in the correct order.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Haha hmm, if it could then that would make things interesting... I could also use virtual methods to avoid conditional jumps! That would be a rather hilarious attempt at making branchless code.

Comment: @Mehrdad: no, that's cheating! An "unconditional" jump to a computed address can hardly be any easier for the CPU to optimize than a regular conditional branch, which at least has only two possible outcomes. A non-inlined function call is a "branch" in the important sense that execution doesn't continue through consecutive instructions.

Comment: @SteveJessop: lol yeah I know, that's why I said it'd be hilarious :P