# std::map vs unordered_map memory footprint for small N

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, dictionary, optimization

For embedded system applications where **memory usage** is more of a concern than speed, what would be the best map container to use? `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`? This would be for situations where `N` is less than, say, a hundred.

**If implementation matters, then I'm concerned with the libstdc++ implementation (GCC).**

While I understand that it's impossible to beat a simple array for memory usage, I want to avoid a data structure that has O(N) performance. So while I want to reduce memory footprint, I also want the **lookup** speed to be reasonable (better than O(N)). I don't care about other operations (insertions, removals), as they will occur infrequently.

If I wanted to make my own memory usage measurements, how would I go about doing this on a Linux platform?

Would [boost::flat_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html) be suitable as an associative container with small footprint and lookup times better than O(n)?

Comment: Before you all start rushing in to close this question as a duplicate, please note that I'm concerned with **memory usage**, not speed. I could not find a question or answer that addresses memory usage.

Comment: if memory usage is a concern, then use an array (either a primitive array or `std::array`.)

Comment: Hmm, yes, it seems pretty obvious now that there's no way a tree or hash-based map could possibly use less memory than a simple array. I'll revise my question a bit.

Comment: `O(n)` for what operations? If you fill an array and sort it, searching will then be faster than a map.

Comment: @EmileCormier Specifically which operations' complexity do you want to be better than `O(N)`? A sorted array can perform lookup in `O(log N)`, insertion and deletion in `O(N)`. An open-addressing hash table can achieve amortized `O(1)` insertion and lookup, and if implemented properly, deletion, although for practical purposes, it's advisable to keep the load factor below around 2/3.

Comment: As you were typing those comments, I was just now remembering that I can simply sort the vector for O(log N) lookup performance. Thanks for the help, I think I'll be deleting this question.

Comment: Don't delete it.  It's a useful discussion for other people to see in the future.

Comment: (Although you might wan to post an answer and accept it when you can so it stops getting sorted up looking for an accepted answer)

Comment: @Donnie Okay, I'll leave my temporary lapse in Data Structures 101 here as an example for others. ;-P

Comment: We've all been there.  I have an embarrassing Java question laying around too.

Comment: You guys go ahead an answer. I'm now curious to know if `boost::flat_map` somehow uses sorting to improve lookup times.

Comment: A `map` is typically implemented as a binary tree (rb-tree), this means 2 pointers overhead per element, plus the overhead of one allocation per element. It has parent pointers, too, and a color. An `unordered_map` is typically implemented as an array of linked lists, which implies one pointer overhead per element plus the array of pointers (which should be about as big as the number of elements in the un_map) plus allocation overhead per element and for the array. An `unordered_map` typically contains some empty buckets.

Comment: I updated the question to indicate I'm concerned only with lookup performance.

Comment: As containers support custom allocators, you could provide a custom allocator which measures the memory consumption (in addition to the `sizeof` the map object itself).

Comment: This question is completely unanswerable. The only possible way to answer the question is to profile the implementation you're using, which is not possible for anyone else.

Comment: @Puppy I've constrained the question to GCC. I'm sure there are plenty others who use it and who might be interested. Did dyp not suggest a means to measure the memory consumption?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For small N, a sorted vector is often the fastest container, and has minimal memory footprint. boost::flat_map is an implementation, others call it AssociativeVector. You can use `std::lower_bound` to implement it easily. Since the data has to be sorted, insert and delete operations are O(n) since the data has to be shifted in the vector.

With a sorted vector, you can do a binary search which is O(log N) for retrieval. The complexity of `std::lower_bound` is:

> The number of comparisons performed is logarithmic in the distance between first and last (At most log2(last - first) + O(1) comparisons)

Comment: If you can clarify that a sorted vector is fast *for retrievals*, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Note that for extremely small N, [it's faster to use std::find than std::lower_bound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8784732/86436).

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative [my answer on `vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32160634/4143855), you could also consider a hash-map if you know the keys in advance. You could use gperf to generate a perfect hash function, and then have O(1) lookup. The real speed depends on the key type. I've seen cases where a `std::map<string>` outperformed a `std::unordered_map<string>` because the hash function for strings has to process the complete key string while the map comparison function often stops after the first few characters.

If speeds matters, implement both and benchmark. For heap profiling, I've used  [google perftools](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/heap_profiler.html) in the past.

Comment: Not only is this O(1) lookup, but it could reduce the memory consumption for a hash map from 2 pointers plus one allocation per value (`unordered_map`) to to either 1 value per key, or 1 value plus 1 bool per key (`optional<value>`).

Comment: While I'm not *that* constrained for memory and speed, this is useful to know for situations where I might be.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to a sorted vector (like `boost::flat_map`) you may also have a look at `google::dense_hash_map`, which is a hash map storing the data contiguously opposed to `std::unordered_map`, which allocates nodes separately. The price is the need for a dedicated empty key value and lack of iterator invalidation guarantees. There is also an even more compact `google::sparse_hash_map` (although slower).

Answer (score 2):

If insertions and deletions occur infrequently, then instead of `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, why not use a sorted `std::vector` and `std::lower_bound` or `std::equal_range` for lookup - you get `ln(N)` speed for the lookups and minimal space. `boost::flat_map` provides a nice associative container API that is implemented in precisely this way. Some detailed benchmarks are provides [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166675/boostflat-map-and-its-performance-compared-to-map-and-unordered-map) and [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/insert-and-remove-performance-of-boosts-flat_set-v-s-stdset/). Another option would be an open-address hash-table. You'd have to do some experimenting to see whether this would satisfy your memory constraints and still give you faster lookup than `ln(N)`. Both solutions give good locality but if you want zero memory overhead and `ln(N)` is fast enough for lookups, then I'd go with the sorted array.

Comment: If you can add a blurb about `boost::flat_map` having fast lookups and being implemented like a sorted `std::vector`, I'll accept this answer.