# Why is a binary search over a sorted vector is slower than std::set find?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector, set

Here you can see the code, run it and see the times.

http://rextester.com/MNQZS47293

I get similar results on my machine (using the same version of MSVC), the lookup in the vector is slower than in the std::set.

I would expect the sorted vector version to be faster, due to better locality of the data (more cache friendly). 
In the worse case, I would expect them to be similar, because they both perform a binary search, but I cannot understand why the std::set is much faster than the sorted vector version.

Thank you very much

Edit: Sorry, I pasted the wrong link (I modified the code but forgot to copy the link) the old code was using an unordered_set, this code is using a set, and the question remains the same: Why is the binary search over a sorted vector slower than over a set? I've noticed that if the number of elements is large enough, then the sorted vector is faster, but I still cannot understand why the set can outperform the sorted vector for any number of elements.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784732/stdlower-bound-slower-for-stdvector-than-stdmapfind

Comment: Please post code here, providing link only is offtopic on SO

Comment: You have edited the question so the previously correct answer is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the updated question:

`-O1` and `-O2` gives the same performance for the two methods.

`-Ox` slows down the vector version.

Why this is, you need to look at the disassembly or at the details of the `-Ox` level. It has nothing to do with the algorithmic properties of `set.find` and `lower_bound/binary_search`.

Regarding the locality of data. A binary_search and a set::find has for reasonable implementations exactly the same locality of data. The set might even win with the data being read in a left-to-right fashion.

Comment: Cache locality for set can be worse, because each node contains additional pointers, so you can store fewer values per cacheline.

Comment: Old post, but interesting. The set does ok for such a small data set as it's all in the cache in this benchmarked example and unlikely to get evicted due to the small size of the values (8Kb). Even with the overhead of the internals of set the memory is cache friendly. When the number of values is increased to 100k the vector takes a big lead due to superior memory locality and predictability. In the real world, the cache will not just be primed with your data all the time, so I would expect the vector to perform better even in relatively small data structures.

Answer (score 3):

The linked code seem to use `unordered_set`, not `set`.

`unordered_set` is a hash table. There the search is *not* binary search. There, search performance depends on the hash function and the load factor.

Comment: Good spotting! In fact, for decent load factors the search performance of a hash is amortized O(1).